# automated creation of pdf with Matplotlib blocks the code execution

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I have a Python code that contains a function where a figure is created in order to be saved as a pdf (it never shows on the screen during execution). For some reason, the execution of this subroutine keeps the figure open and blocks the following operations in the code. I tried to use the cla(), clf() and clear() functions but I could not get it to work...

Here is a partial view of the subroutine:

```
def trace_pdf(a,b,c,d):
   x = np.linspace(0,100,a)
   fig2 = plt.figure()
   ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)
   ax2.plot(b,c,'b', label='BA',linewidth=3.5)
   ax2.set_title('a pdf like no other')     
   fig2.savefig('file.pdf', format='pdf')       
   fig2.clf()
   fig2.clear()
```

I do not see why my code is blocked... (I checked that if I comment the call to the **trace_pdf** function, everything works fine).

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have a `plt.show()` somewhere else in your code?

Comment: Actually the code has a graphic interface that contains a few figures. So there is a `plt.show()` somewhere else in the code.

Comment: After checking all the source code, there is no plt.show() but canvas.show() that I replaced by canvas.draw(). Still, I can't find a way not to have my code blocked due to the subroutine. I am considering running this subroutine as a separate subprocess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I did to fix my problem. I decided to try to run my function as an independent process so I added to my code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def trace_pdf(a,b,c,d):
   x = np.linspace(0,100,a)
   fig2 = plt.figure()
   ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)
   ax2.plot(b,c,'b', label='BA',linewidth=3.5)
   ax2.set_title('a pdf like no other')     
   fig2.savefig('file.pdf', format='pdf')       
   plt.close()

trace_pdf = Process(target=trace_pdf, args=(a,b,c,d))
trace_pdf.start()
```

This way, the `plt_close()` call does not impact the main graphic interface as I believe its action is limited to the separate process... For details regarding running a function as an independent process I used [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046603/is-it-possible-to-run-function-in-a-subprocess-without-threading-or-writing-a-se)