# How to put an opencv function to play videos in django views?

Tags: python, html, django, opencv

I have some python code that uses opencv to play a video from a certain path and I've been reading about how to incorporate that python code with Django and I saw that the python code can be put into the django views.py file but my question is what am I supposed to put as a parameter for the piece of code that renders it, like `return render(request, [what do I put here?])` because usually after request the location of the html file is put but if I want that video to play do I just specify the html page I want the video to play on, will that work or do I have to do something more? Also if you know any good tutorials that deal with this type of stuff I would appreciate any links. Thanks in advance.

Here's the python code that just plays a video

```
 filename = 'C:/Desktop/Videos/traffic2.mp4'
        vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)

        while(vidcap.isOpened()):
            success, frame_org = vidcap.read()

            cv2.imshow('frame',frame_org)  

            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

        vidcap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Are you asking how to play a video in the client's web browser or do you want a video window to open and play on the server every time a request is made to a certain URL?

Comment: I want a video window to open and play on the server every time a request is made to a certain URL which would be when a button is pressed on the html page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer: Don't bother with templates and `render()`, just use an [`HttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse). The video will play, then the response will be returned so it all works out in the end.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    play_video()
    return HttpResponse("OK")
```

---

Opinions answer:

So I've actually done [something *kinda* similar to this](https://github.com/simon-andrews/mpvrc).

I'd recommend having a main view with the button on it, that when clicked calls a JavaScript function that [sends a GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript) to another *hidden* view that actually plays the video on the server.

This hidden view would basically be the code snippet I posted above.

You may also want to consider putting your video playing code in a [subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046603/is-it-possible-to-run-function-in-a-subprocess-without-threading-or-writing-a-se) because Django or the webbrowser might time out or something.