# How to create a process inside a process using multiprocessing in python?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a function that takes 2 minutes to run.
I call it twice in my program so i  use map from multiprocessing to have them run in parallel.

Now i want to reduce the time even more .

In this function i have 8 operations that can be run in parallel.

So ,what i can do to have 2 main processes run in parallel and inside each one i have another  8 child processes run in parallel too.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run function in a subprocess without threading or writing a separate file/script.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046603/is-it-possible-to-run-function-in-a-subprocess-without-threading-or-writing-a-se)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure why you need such setup but anyway:

```
import _thread
import time

def operation(a, b, s):
    print("Starting operation {} in process {}".format(a,b))
    time.sleep(s)
    print("Finished operation {} in process {}".format(a,b))

def process(n):
    _thread.start_new_thread(operation, (1, n, 1))
    _thread.start_new_thread(operation, (2, n, 2))
    _thread.start_new_thread(operation, (3, n, 1))
    _thread.start_new_thread(operation, (4, n, 2))

_thread.start_new_thread(process, (1,))
_thread.start_new_thread(process, (2,))
time.sleep(3)
```

Works in Python 3.4.

EDIT: As suggested, that multiprocessing may be faster, below same example with multiprocessing

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool as PoolParent
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool
import time

class NoDaemonProcess(Process):
    def _get_daemon(self):
        return False
    def _set_daemon(self, value):
        pass
    daemon = property(_get_daemon, _set_daemon)

class MyPool(PoolParent):
    Process = NoDaemonProcess

def operation(a):
    print("Starting operation {} in process {}".format(a[0],a[1]))
    time.sleep(a[2])
    print("Finished operation {} in process {}".format(a[0],a[1]))

def process(n):
    p = Pool(4)
    p.map(operation, [(1,n,1), (2,n,2), (3,n,1), (4,n,2)])

p = MyPool(2)
p.map(process, [1,2])
time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: @roganjosh I have provided additional example using multiprocessing as you suggested, it is just simpler using `_thread` because of internal locks of `multiprocessing` and requires simple hack to get this work.

Comment: Understood. However, the OP's aim was to improve execution speed; threading cannot achieve that due to the GIL so it leaves no option other than to use multiprocessing.

Comment: @roganjosh ,thank u i'm going to test that and see the results