# Script to kick-off Multiple Instances of another script that takes an input parameter

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a python script (grouper.py) that accepts 1 argument as input. Currently, due to size of the input file, I must break the input argument up into 20 chunks and open 20 terminals and run all 20 at once.

Is there a way to loop through all 10 input arguments that kicks off a python process?

```
def fun(i):
    j = pd.read(i)    
    # do some heavy processing
    return j
```

```
for i in inputfiles:
    print(i)
    outputfile=fun(i)
    outputfile.to_csv('outputfile.csv', index=False)
```

The above code of mine does each inputfile 1 at a time... IS there a way to run all 20 input files at once??

Thanks!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to run function in a subprocess without threading or writing a separate file/script.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046603/is-it-possible-to-run-function-in-a-subprocess-without-threading-or-writing-a-se)

Answer (score 1):

> **Q** : *Script to kick-off multiple instances of another script that takes an input parameter?*

### GNU `parallel` solves this straight from the CLI :

```
parallel python {} ::: file1 file2 file3 ...... file20
```

Given about a 20+ CPU-core machine goes on this, `# do some heavy processing` may remain unconstrained to a *just*-`[CONCURRENT]` CPU-scheduling and may indeed perform the work in an almost `[PARALLEL]` fashion ( without race conditions on ***shared*** resources )

```
for i in inputfiles:
    print(i)
    outputfile=fun(i)
    ...
```

is a pure-`[SERIAL]` iterator, producing just a sequence of passes, so launching the process straight from CLI may be the cheapest ever solution. Python **`joblib`** and other multi-processing tools can spawn copies of the running python-interpreter, yet that will be at rather remarkable add-on cost, if just a batch-operated processing from a single CLI command may suffice the target - to process a known list of files into another set of output files.

Comment: Also: If you are splitting a big file into chunks to process each chunk, look at `parallel --pipepart`. It may just be doing that for you on-the-fly. That way you do not need to have space for two copies of `bigfile`.