# keras model.save() issues RuntimeError: Unable to flush file's cached information

Tags: keras, databricks

I'm facing some issues with my databricks cluster configuration, and issue is that i'm not able to put a finger on where and why.
I was trying to save a keras model, and it seems to be not going well

```
dataset = pd.DataFrame([item.split(',') for item in '''6,148,72,35,0,33.6,0.627,50,1
1,85,66,29,0,26.6,0.351,31,0
8,183,64,0,0,23.3,0.672,32,1
1,89,66,23,94,28.1,0.167,21,0
0,137,40,35,168,43.1,2.288,33,1'''.split('\n')])

X = dataset.iloc[:,0:8]
y = dataset.iloc[:,8]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, epochs=3, batch_size=10)

accuracy = model.evaluate(X, y, verbose=0)
print(accuracy)
```

The issue is with saving the model, can anyone help me understand what the error is all about
I'm using Python 3.7.3, DBRuntime 6.2 (includes Apache Spark 2.4.4, Scala 2.11)

```
model.save('/dbfs/FileStore/tables/temp/new_model.h5')
```

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   /databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py
>   in save_model(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
>       540         with H5Dict(filepath, mode='w') as h5dict:
>   --> 541             _serialize_model(model, h5dict, include_optimizer)
>       542     elif hasattr(filepath, 'write') and callable(filepath.write):
>
> /databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py
>   in _serialize_model(model, h5dict, include_optimizer)
>       160         for name, val in zip(weight_names, weight_values):
>   --> 161             layer_group[name] = val
>       162     if include_optimizer and model.optimizer:
>
> /databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/io_utils.py
>   in **setitem**(self, attr, val)
>       230             raise KeyError('Cannot set attribute. '
>   --> 231                            'Group with name "{}" exists.'.format(attr))
>       232         if is_np:
>
> KeyError: 'Cannot set attribute. Group with name
>   "b\'dense_1/kernel:0\'" exists.'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 model.save('/dbfs/FileStore/tables/temp/new_model.h5')
>
> /databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py
>   in save(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)    1150
>   raise NotImplementedError    1151         from ..models import
>   save_model
>   -> 1152         save_model(self, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)    1153     1154     @saving.allow_write_to_gcs
>
> /databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py
>   in save_wrapper(obj, filepath, overwrite, *args, **kwargs)
>       447                 os.remove(tmp_filepath)
>       448         else:
>   --> 449             save_function(obj, filepath, overwrite, *args, **kwargs)
>       450 
>       451     return save_wrapper
>
> /databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py
>   in save_model(model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
>       539                 return
>       540         with H5Dict(filepath, mode='w') as h5dict:
>   --> 541             _serialize_model(model, h5dict, include_optimizer)
>       542     elif hasattr(filepath, 'write') and callable(filepath.write):
>       543         # write as binary stream
>
> /databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/io_utils.py
>   in **exit**(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)
>       368 
>       369     def **exit**(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
>   --> 370         self.close()
>       371 
>       372
>
> /databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/io_utils.py
>   in close(self)
>       344     def close(self):
>       345         if isinstance(self.data, h5py.Group):
>   --> 346             self.data.file.flush()
>       347             if self._is_file:
>       348                 self.data.close()
>
> /databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py in
>   flush(self)
>       450         """
>       451         with phil:
>   --> 452             h5f.flush(self.id)
>       453 
>       454     @with_phil
>
> h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()
>
> h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()
>
> h5py/h5f.pyx in h5py.h5f.flush()
>
> RuntimeError: Unable to flush file's cached information (file write
>   failed: time = Fri Jan 31 08:19:53 2020 , filename =
>   '/dbfs/FileStore/tables/temp/new_model.h5', file descriptor = 9, errno
>   = 95, error message = 'Operation not supported', buf = 0x6993c98, total write size = 320, bytes this sub-write = 320, bytes actually
>   written = 18446744073709551615, offset = 800)

Comment: i just tried your code(not with databricks), everything works fine for me, could you wrapp everything in one function and pass it to a process? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046603/is-it-possible-to-run-function-in-a-subprocess-without-threading-or-writing-a-se

Comment: What filesystem is /dbfs on? It could be that it does not support some low level operations required for HDF5 to work with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to save the model, by saving it on driver only and copying it on s3...

```
import os
import shutil
classification_model.save('news_dedup_model.h5')
shutil.copyfile('/databricks/driver/news_dedup_model.h5', '/dbfs/FileStore/tables/temp/nemish/news_dedup_model.h5')

classification_model = load_model('/dbfs/FileStore/tables/temp/nemish/news_dedup_model.h5', custom_objects={'tf': tf})
```

Still unable to figure out, why wouldn't it save normally

Answer (score 1):

Because keras model.save() doesn't support writing to a FUSE mount. Doing so you'll get 'Operation Not Supported' error.

You need to first write it to the driver node's local disk (where python's working directory is), then move it to DFBS FUSE mount using '/dbfs/your/path/on/DBFS'.

Comment: Hey Thanks, have you come across any github issue link in this regard?