# Terminate a python thread that calls gdal functions

Tags: python, multithreading, gdal

i have a program that uses gdal to process pictures. That is done in a thread that is started with a button click.
Now, i need a way to terminate this thread at any given point, also with a button click. So i defined a function that i call when the button is clicked:

```
def terminateThread(self):
   self.change_button_caption.emit('Start')
   self.print_log.emit('Vorgang abgebrochen')
   self.show_progress.emit(0)
   self.terminate()
```

When i replace the actual code with a sleep order, this works. But it doesn't when the thread called a gdal function.
How can i achieve the termination of this thread at any time?

this is the thread:

```
class MapThread(QThread):
    print_log = Signal(str)
    show_progress = Signal(int)
    change_button_caption = Signal(str)

    def __init__(self, path, tab_filelist, targetpath):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.path = path
        self.tab_filelist = tab_filelist
        self.targetpath = targetpath

    def run(self):
        self.change_button_caption.emit('Stop')
        print('MapThread run', flush=True)
        # try:
        from osgeo import gdal
        from osgeo import osr
        self.show_progress.emit(0)

        filename = self.tab_filelist[0].rsplit('\\', 1)[1].rsplit('.', 1)[0]
        path2 = self.targetpath + "\\" + filename + ".vrt"
        pathout = self.targetpath + "\\" + filename + ".mbtiles"

        d = gdal.Open(self.path)
        proj = osr.SpatialReference(wkt=d.GetProjection())
        self.print_log.emit('EPSG Code der Bilddaten: ' + proj.GetAttrValue('AUTHORITY', 1))
        # Vituelles Raster erzeugen
        vrt_options = gdal.BuildVRTOptions(resampleAlg='cubic', outputSRS=proj)
        gdal.BuildVRT(path2, self.tab_filelist, options=vrt_options)

        print('VRT Datei erzeugt', flush=True)
        self.print_log.emit('VRT Datei erzeugt')
        self.show_progress.emit(10)
        # mbtiles generieren
        creation_options = ["TILE_FORMAT=JPEG", "QUALITY=90"]
        
        src_ds = gdal.Open(path2)
        gdal.Translate(pathout, src_ds, format='mbtiles', creationOptions=creation_options)
        print('MB Tiles generiert', flush=True)
        self.print_log.emit('MB Tiles generiert')
        self.show_progress.emit(75)
        # Overviews erzeugen
        Image = gdal.Open(pathout, 1)
        gdal.SetConfigOption("COMPRESS_OVERVIEW", "DEFLATE")
        Image.BuildOverviews("AVERAGE", [2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048])
        self.show_progress.emit(100)
        print('Overviews erfolgreich berechnet', flush=True)
        self.print_log.emit('Overviews erfolgreich berechnet')
        self.change_button_caption.emit('Start')
        # except Exception as err:
        #     print(err)

    def terminateThread(self):
        self.change_button_caption.emit('Start')
        self.print_log.emit('Vorgang abgebrochen')
        self.show_progress.emit(0)
        self.terminate()
```

and the functions for comunicating with the ui:

```
@Slot(str)
def printLog(self, msg):
    self.ui.list_status.addItem(msg)

@Slot(int)
def showProgress(self, value):
    self.ui.progressBar.setValue(value)

@Slot(str)
def changeCaption(self, txt):
    self.ui.btn_start_mbtiles.setText(txt)
```

Comment: You'd better provide complete code that can reproduce the problem, or at lease a version with `sleep()`. Also it is generally a bad idea to terminate a thread from outside. More common apporoach that thead itself checks some variable and decides to or not to return from it's main function.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like gdal library is a binding - non-python code is called from python. So python's `terminate()` just can't stop it until execution returned to the python part. If you need to terminate your function immediatly, you may use processes instead of threads.

This may be helpful:

[Is it possible to run function in a subprocess without threading or writing a separate file/script.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046603/is-it-possible-to-run-function-in-a-subprocess-without-threading-or-writing-a-se)

Comment: i took the code from the run() methode of the thread and made a function from it that i started within a new Process. I also tried subprocess.Popen. But it's always the same. The button i need to click to terminate the process is blocked.