# Python Pandas leaking memory?

Tags: python, pandas, memory-leaks

I have a script that is constantly measuring some data and regularly storing it in a file. In the past I was storing the data in a "manually created CSV" file in this way (pseudocode):

```
with open('data.csv','w') as ofile:
    print('var1,var2,var3,...,varN', file=ofile) # Create CSV header.
    while measure:
        do_something()
        print(f'{var1},{var2},{var3},...,{varN}', file=ofile) # Store data.
```

I worked in this way for several months and runned this script several hundreds of times with no issues other than 1) this is cumbersome (and prone to errors) when N is large (in my case between 20 and 30) and 2) CSV does not preserve data types. So I decided to change to something like this:

```
temporary_df = pandas.DataFrame()
while measure:
    do_something()
    temporary_df.append({'var1':var1,'var2':var2,...,'varN':varN}, ignore_index=True)
    if save_data_in_this_iteration():
        temporary_df.to_feather(f'file_{datetime.datetime.now()}.fd')
        temporary_df = pandas.DataFrame() # Clean the dataframe.
merge_all_feathers_into_single_feather()
```

At a first glance this was working perfectly as I expected. However, after some hours Python crashes. After experiencing this both in a Windows and in a (separate) Linux machine I, I noticed that the problem is that Python is slowly sucking the memory of the machine until there is no more memory, and then of course it crashes.

As the function `do_something` is unchanged between the two approaches, and the crash happens before `merge_all_feathers_into_single_feather` is called, and `save_data_in_this_iteration` is trivially simple, I am blaming Pandas for this problem.

Google has told me that other people in the past have had memory problems while using Pandas. I have tried adding the garbage collector line in each iteration, as suggested e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49144260/8849755), but did not worked for me. I didn't tried the [mutiprocessing approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39101287/8849755) yet because it looks like killing an ant with a nuke, and may bring other complications...

Is there any solution to keep using Pandas like this? Is there a better solution to this without using Pandas? Which?

Comment: Tbh the multiprocessing solution is what I would go for. It's not really "killing an ant with a nuke", it's the only guaranteed way you have to ensure all memory used by pandas when writing the Feather file is actually released. I would maybe not use `Pool(1)`, but rather explicitly use a `Process` [as done here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2046630/3214872), but the underlying idea is the same.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will try that. I have just made a simple MWE with Pandas and there were no memory issues, so there might be something else hidden. I will post updates in a couple of days after testing the multiprocessing approach.

Answer (score 0):

## Pandas was not the problem

After struggling with this problem for a while, I decided to create a MWE to do some tests. So I wrote this:

```
import pandas
import numpy
import datetime

df = pandas.DataFrame()
while True:
    df = df.append({f'col_{i}': numpy.random.rand() for i in range(99)}, ignore_index=True)
    if 'last_clean' not in locals() or (datetime.datetime.now()-last_clean).seconds > .5:
        last_clean = datetime.datetime.now()
        df.to_feather('delete_me.fd')
        df = df[0:0]
```

To my surprise, the memory is not drained by this script! So here I concluded that Pandas was not my problem.

Then I added a new component to the MWE and I found the issue:

```
import pandas
import numpy
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def save_matplotlib_plot(df):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(df['col_1'], df['col_2'])
    fig.savefig('delete_me.png')
    # Uncomment the following two lines to release the memory and stop the "leak".
    # ~ fig.clear()
    # ~ plt.close(fig)

df = pandas.DataFrame()
while True:
    df = df.append({f'col_{i}': numpy.random.rand() for i in range(99)}, ignore_index=True)
    if 'last_clean' not in locals() or (datetime.datetime.now()-last_clean).seconds > .5:
        last_clean = datetime.datetime.now()
        df.to_feather('delete_me.fd')
        save_matplotlib_plot(df) # Here I had my "leak" (which was not a leak indeed because matplotlib keeps track of all the figures it creates, so it was working as expected).
        df = df[0:0]
```

It seems that when I switched from "handmade CSV" to "Pandas" I also changed something with the plots, so I was blaming Pandas when it was not the problem.

Just for completeness, the multiprocessing solution also works. The following script has no memory issues:

```
import pandas
import numpy
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from multiprocessing import Process

def save_matplotlib_plot(df):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(df['col_1'], df['col_2'])
    fig.savefig('delete_me.png')

df = pandas.DataFrame()
while True:
    df = df.append({f'col_{i}': numpy.random.rand() for i in range(99)}, ignore_index=True)
    if 'last_clean' not in locals() or (datetime.datetime.now()-last_clean).seconds > .5:
        last_clean = datetime.datetime.now()
        df.to_feather('delete_me.fd')
        p = Process(target=save_matplotlib_plot, args=(df,))
        p.start()
        p.join()
        df = df[0:0]
```